# format on internet explorer does not match other browsers

Tags: html, css

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2gSj/

in internet explorer the search bar is located under the 'contact us'. however it should be like the jsfiddle (on the right side of the menu bar).

what is preventing it from doing this?

Comment: Duplicate from OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829298/code-working-in-all-browsers-but-ie-fix

Comment: this will show allright on ie8/9 (not 7 due since your html needs a fix)
http://jsfiddle.net/n4gSj/3/

Comment: that seems to have sorted that issue but now when I hover over the search area I have a large grey box which covers the size of the div. The box is like the drop down when you hoover over a menu title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try wrapping the form in a li ?

You will want to update the CSS rules on the li elements so that some only apply to the menu items.

Look at the rule here: #NOINTERFERE00_menu li:hover (This one applies a grey box around the element on hover)

I have added a class isMenuItem to your li tags if the li represents a menu item and then I have updated the CSS rule which creates the grey box to only apply to menu items.

Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/n4gSj/5/

Comment: well that works but now when i click on the search box it it comes up with a large grey box. (like when you hoover over the drop down)

Comment: You will want to update your CSS rules so they only apply to the menu items.

Look at the rule here: #NOINTERFERE00_menu li:hover